# How to programmatically add tags to a GCP dataset

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, tags, google-iam, policies

Have no ideas how to programmatically add tags to a GCP dataset [Ad Tag](https://prnt.sc/e2f22409qTc1). I can create and manage tagKeys&tagValues, can add conditions to policies but I can't get how to add tags to dataset using Python:

Can't find any information in GCP documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the CloudResourceManager [API to manage the TAGS](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/tagBindings#TagBinding). By API, you can do like that

*My dataset is in multiregion US*

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
 -d '{"parent":"//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/gdglyon-cloudrun/datasets/dlp_test","tagValue":"tagValues/252755946221"}' \
 "https://us-cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v3/tagBindings"
```

I tried to use the [CloudResourceManager client library](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudresourcemanager/latest/google.cloud.resourcemanager_v3.services.tag_bindings.TagBindingsClient). And it's not very easy (and I'm bad at Python). But that piece of code works

```
    from google.cloud import resourcemanager_v3

    location = "us"
    # Create a client
    api_endpoint, _ = resourcemanager_v3.TagBindingsClient.get_mtls_endpoint_and_cert_source()    
    client = resourcemanager_v3.TagBindingsClient(client_options={"api_endpoint": location + "-" + api_endpoint})


    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = resourcemanager_v3.CreateTagBindingRequest()
    request.tag_binding.parent = "//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/gdglyon-cloudrun/datasets/dlp_test"
    request.tag_binding.tag_value = "tagValues/252755946221"

    # Make the request
    operation = client.create_tag_binding(request=request)

    print("Waiting for operation to complete...")

    response = operation.result()

    # Handle the response
    print(response)
```

Note that I had to get the API endpoint from the client, and then create the client with a hack on the api-endpoint. Indeed, for local resources, you have to use the cloud resource manager API in that same location. But I didn't find a clean way to achieve that with the client library!

Comment: Thank you very much! My knowledge of Google APIs needs improvement as well as the APIs itself ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the [API definition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets#Dataset), you can add tags in the dataset object

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this way too but: [proof](https://prnt.sc/0wMK8ykgEIvE). So you are not able to create or update it :(

Comment: I also tried to use [Cloud Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/tagBindings) it wants resource location which cannot be added

Comment: Correct, output only. Let me answer again, with something working.